# Why does VideoCapture isOpened() fail with my working camera using OpenCV on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: opencv, video-capture, raspberry-pi2

Hardware:

- Raspberry Pi 2 B
- OS: Raspbian (Debian Wheezy, released 05.05.2015)
- OpenCV 3.0.0 (released 04.06.2015)

I am working with a camera on the CSI Port of the Raspberry Pi. The command

```cpp
raspistill -o test.jpg
```

works fine: it takes a picture and saves it on my Raspberry. So the camera works well.

In June, I displayed the camera and could apply some other functions like detecting edges or lines. A few days ago, I wanted to go further but suddenly I had problems with imshow.

For example the following code worked in June but now returns the error

```cpp
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 271
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:271: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Here is the code that worked in June:

```cpp
#include <cv.hpp>
#include <cxcore.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c;

    Mat image;
    VideoCapture video;

    video.open(0);

    while(1)
    {
        video >> image;
        imshow("test", image);

        c=waitKey(10);
        if (c==27)
            break;
    }

    video.release();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to solve my problem by adding code to mine (like delay, resizing, check if the video opened, check if the image to display is not empty) or by deleting some (like vid.open). However, it still does not work. What I get is always "opening video... video did not open". That means that the test vid.isOpened returns always false. I tried to open another video (even if my camera is not the problem as it works with raspistill, as explained below) but the error is the same, isOpened is false.

Here is my modified code:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat image;
    VideoCapture vid(0); // open the default camera
    //VideoCapture vid("/home/pi/video.mp4"); // open a video file
    cout << "opening video... ";

    waitKey(1000); // add delay if the camera did not have time to open correctly

    //vid.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640); // resize
    //vid.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

    //vid.open(0); // do not open twice, already done in VideoCapture vid(0)

    if(!vid.isOpened()) // check if video is successfully opened
    {
        cout << "video did not open ";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "video opened correctly ";

    namedWindow( "test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); // prepare the window

    waitKey(1000); // add delay if the camera did not have time to open correctly

    cout << "before while loop ";

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "inside while loop ";
        vid >> image; // get a frame from camera
        if(!image.empty()) // wait for the image to be taken
        {
            cout << "displaying image ";
            imshow("test", image); // display it
        } else {
            cout << "image empty ";
        }

        if (waitKey(10)==27) // waiting for esc key to be pressed for 10ms
            break;

    }

    vid.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me fix this? I really do not see why I have this problem now, as it worked perfectly in June, and I did not change anything on my Raspberry.
Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:  I think the last thing I can do is reinstalling everything (OS Raspbian and OpenCV), as it worked perfectly in June without installing any of the additional libraries you proposed in the answers. I really don't know what changed between June and now, as nobody touched anything on the Raspberry, my code just doesn't work anymore :(

EDIT2: Code used with PiCapture library:

```cpp
#include <cv.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "/home/pi/PiCapture/src/PiCapture.cpp"


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    PiCapture cap;
    namedWindow("PiCapture");
    cap.open(320, 240, true); // 320 width, 240 height, color true

    while(1)
    {
        Mat img;
        img = cap.grab(); // get a frame from camera
        if(!image.empty()) // wait for the image to be taken
        {
            imshow("PiCapture", img); // display it
        }
        if (waitKey(10)==27) // waiting for esc key to be pressed for 10ms
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try connecting with `vid(CV_CAP_ANY)` instead. This might actually just be equivalent to `vid(0)`...I forget what the value of `CV_CAP_ANY` is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work either. I have read in the VideoCapture class definition file that 0 already the default camera is. And I only have one camera connected to my Raspberry Pi...

Answer (score 2):

sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2

load the pre-installed video for linux drivers for the cv video capture method

Comment: This is indeed what solved my problem. I was using Raspberry Pi 3 with opencv installed and apparently only v4l2 loading was missing causing the opencv to fail.

Comment: Great! Please mark the response as the answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue a while back and put together a nice little wrapper for the Raspberry Pi Camera Module so you can easily retrieve images as `cv::Mat`.

There's a plain c++ version: [PiCapture](https://github.com/orgicus/PiCapture) and an [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc) addon version: [ofxCvPiCam](https://github.com/orgicus/ofxCvPiCam)

[image: PiCapture]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to clone from git, but then did not found the files in the src folder. So I created it and copied the content of the files in each corresponding file. Then with Code Blocks I tried to build main.cpp but I had a lot of libraries which couldn't be found. I gave the full path with /home/pi/userland/... for each library, but there are some files that do not exist in the userland folder (I searched with the search tool). So I couldn't test this code, it's a shame.

Comment: Hi Anais, please follow the [setup instructions](https://github.com/orgicus/PiCapture#how-to-use-the-sample). In short 1. clone the userland repo, 2. update the CMakeLists.txt file to point to where you downloaded the userland repo on your Pi, 3. continue with the typical cmake setup (make a build folder, enter it, run ```cmake..```, then ```make```

Comment: OK, I'll try it. When I cloned the repo it had an other README file which said to just execute the "buildme" executable. Maybe there's a difference...

Comment: There is no USERLAND_DIR in the CMakeLists file so I could not replace it with my path. I ran cmake but at the end the command ./main did not work as there is no main file in the userland folder.

Comment: Once you clone the userland repo, you shouldn't need to build or compile anything there. It contains the header files for the camera interface, which the PiCapture references. USERLAND_DIR is at [line 9 in CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/orgicus/PiCapture/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L9). Replace USERLAND_DIR with the path of the userland repo you just cloned. After you that, in a terminal window, inside the PiCapture repo folder create a build folder and enter it: ```mkdir build && cd build```, then run cmake: ```cmake ..```, then ```make``` which will compile main for you and you can run it

Comment: Then I have to clone https://github.com/orgicus/PiCapture too... It is written to only clone the userland repo, I misunderstood and searched for USERLAND_DIR in the CMakeLists from userland. I'll try tomorrow with the repo PiCapture!

Comment: Oh dear, I'll update the instructions. You're totally right, it's not clear which repo's CMakeLists needs updating. Perhaps a short gif/video or image sequence might help. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Your main works, I can see the video feed. But I then would like to extract each frame of the video to display it (and do some operations on it, when it will work). I used the code that you can see in my original post in EDIT2, it should be correct. But when I build my code, I get an error in PiCapture.cpp that bcm_host.h does not exist. I tryed to give the full path but it still says it does not exist! Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear you've managed to compile and run the code. I am not sure how you're setting up the include paths and how you link libraries. This includes looks a bit odd:```#include "/home/pi/PiCapture/src/PiCapture.cpp"``. I would've assume you would copy PiCapture.cpp and cap.h to your project and replicate the include paths and linking from the CMAKE file. I would probably just make a copy of the PiCapture project, the modify main.cpp to fit goals.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV does not see raspiCam as a camera. I prefer to use system() command to get frame from raspiCam and save that somewhere in the filesystem. After that you can load it in your program as a image. Or you can try this [BlogPost](https://robidouille.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv/).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this code: system("raspistill -o testimage.jpg");
        namedWindow( "test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        Mat img = imread("testimage.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
        imshow("test", img); but it shows no window with the image. And the raspistill command is too long, I need to use the camera on an autonomous vehicle so the frame rate has to be high. I don't know if it is normal, but before taking a picture, I see a video for 2-3 seconds before the camera really takes a picture.

Comment: Actually when I try a really simple program like: Mat img = imread("/home/pi/name.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
        imshow("test", img); I still see nothing in imshow. I just have a terminal window open, with "process returned 0" but I can see no image window...

Comment: I wanted to test the Robidouille package but when trying to build the RaspiCam library I have an error (by doing "make"): /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:49:4: error: #error base.hpp header must be compiled as C++
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:52:19: fatal error: climits: No such file or directory /// compilation terminated.
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'objs/RaspiCamCV.o' failed. So unfortunately I couldn't test this library either, same for userland.